# Which layer(IP/TCP?) is netcat/socat working on?

Tags: ssh, netcat

I have this question because I want to know when we use netcat to do the traffic forwarding during 3 machine(A->B->C) ssh tunneling, is it possible for C to know A's IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netcat` is an _application layer tool.  It operates at the higher layers of the OSI stack (layer 7).  So in a naive setup, computer C can not directly see computer A; the source of the IP traffic will appear to be from B. At an IP layer, all traffic will look like it originated from B because the `netcat` application is initiating and making the connection.

However the OSI stack is limited in application; when you think of VPNs and protocol tunneling, it is possible to route IP (layer 3) over an application layer (layer 7); now things get more confusing.

So the answer depends on your setup.

And that's just the transport layer.  Application layer data can easily leak source addresses.  So C *could* learn A's address even if there's no direct communication between them.

Comment: The OSI model, despite being widely taught, [doesn't apply to IP protocols](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3439#section-3).

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title, `netcat` uses TCP by default, but offers a UDP mode with the -u flag. `socat` can use a wide variety of protocols, including TCP, UDP, SCTP, and even netlink sockets on Linux; it also offers raw IP sockets (but you have to be root to use them).

To answer your real question, it can't really be discerned from B what A's IP address is. However, the underlying protocol might leak the IP address inadvertently. IRC servers could, for instance, advertise what IP they're truly listening on, and it might be possible to get an HTTP server to leak an IP in some cases. This could be mitigated (except via possible exploits in the server software) by only listening on localhost, then forwarding the port from localhost to machine B, then from B to C.